# javascript function is calling more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript code ( which is too long , so i can`t put it here ), functions are calling more than once , like suppose :

```
 $("#button").bind({ click : Call }); // bind the Call with button click event

 function Call()
 {
   alert("This message shows me more than once when i clicked the button");
 }
```

if this alert message shows me more than once it means function `Call()` is calling more than once. Can anybody guess or tell me what's going on in my code? (Please don't ask me for code)

Comment: cannot see any issue here? **made a demo for you** http://jsfiddle.net/GRLs3/

Comment: Isn't `Call` bound to an underlaying container's `click` too? And also... this could be browser-related, so - which browser?

Comment: Asking questions that say "my code has a problem. I'm not going to post any real code, but it's something like 'some made up code that's sort of like it'" is like going to your mechanic and saying "My car's making a funny noise. I'm not going to bring it in for you to look at it, but it's the same kind of car as the one parked over there, and it sounds like a car that drove by here a couple of minutes ago. What's wrong, and how much to fix it?"

Answer (score 1):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/aC8Bm/

I'm guessing that you are binding more than once somewhere.

Also, I'd recommend either returning false from the Call function, or stopping event propagation.

One more thing: avoid naming functions with an uppercase -- that's reserved for constructor functions by convention.

Answer (score 1):

You're hooking the event handler to the button the number of times 'Call' is being called.  Do you have this code in something like a template or partial file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this inside any function:

```
$("#button").bind({ click : Call });
```

Place the following somewhere outside:

```
$("#button").live("click", Call);
```

It will bind once for all existing and ever added #button